# Keep an absolute positioned div of unknown height and width centered on the screen when it is scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to keep an absolute positioned `div` of unknown height and width centered on the screen when it is scrolled. The `divs` only parent is the `body` element (which can be fixed or relative if it makes a difference). The following code will center it in the window, but it will scroll off the page.

I prefer a CSS solution but am open to a javascript one as well - I presume capturing the scroll event and centering with each move.

Thanks!

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/tj164ery/)

```
<div class="page-container"></div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>

body {
    width:100%;
}
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width:978px; 
    width: 100%;
    min-height:2500px; 
    margin:0 auto -50px auto; 
    border:solid #999;
    border-width:2px;
    background: lightblue;
}

#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background:lightyellow;
    z-index: 200;
    /* set min just to have something to show  - it will be variable*/
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    /*************/
}
```

Comment: height:100%, width:100%, margin:auto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to use `position: fixed` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/jLvgw6qj/

Comment: Thank you. Simple but effective.